# Color white pixels in c#

Tags: c#

I want to color the white pixels(R,G,B>150)in a Bitmap image with the closest colored pixel (R,G,B <150), more exactly I want that every white pixels be colored.

```
   for (int X = 1; X < myBitmap.Width-1; X++)
        {
            for (int Y = 1; Y < myBitmap.Height-1; Y++)
            {
                pix = myBitmap.GetPixel(X, Y);
                pixx = myBitmap.GetPixel(X-1, Y-1);
                Color pixwhite = myBitmap.GetPixel(X, Y);
                Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(X - 1, Y - 1);

                if (pix.R > 150 && pix.G > 150 && pix.B > 150)
                {
                    Color myWhite = new Color();
                    Color myColor = new Color();
                    myWhite = Color.FromArgb(pix.R, pix.G, pix.B);

                    if (pixx.R < 150 && pixx.G < 150 && pixx.B < 150)
                    {
                        myColor = Color.FromArgb(pixx.R, pixx.G, pixx.B);
                        if (pixwhite != pixelColor)
                        {
                            myBitmap.SetPixel(X, Y, myColor);

                        }

                    }

                }
                else                   
                    myBitmap.SetPixel(X, Y, pix);
            }
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, myBitmap.Width, 0, myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height);
    }
```

It is clearly that I made something wrong, so can someone help me to figure it out ?

Comment: *It is clearly that I made something wrong*, no, it is not.  You must [edit] and tell us what you wanted to happen, what happened, and why it did not work for you.  If there are exceptions thrown, you must provide us full exception details (call ToString() on the exception object).

Comment: *It is clearly that I made something wrong,* it isn't. provide some sample so we can see the behavior.

Comment: [mcve], please provide one.

Comment: The white pixels are still white. More exactly, If I have a image and a part of the image is missing , I want to complete it with the color of the closest pixel.

Comment: Do you have example pictures?

Comment: Olivier, I changed some things and now the white spaces is coloured with a uniform color, like grey, in my case. And you have right, I don't know why I used two different pixels. The idea is to take the closest coloured pixels and make a mean and color the white ones.

Comment: I was thinking to make the euclidean distance from the white pixel and a coloured one and when he finds the closest one , color him with the same color, the code for general cases to calculate the euclidean distance is simple but i don't know how to put it for pixels...

Comment: If you want to replace bad pixels with good ones, you must have a way to identify good pixels. If you blindly take another pixel, that one might be bad as well. I would take the average of all good pixels around a good one, i.e. look in a 3 x 3 square for good pixels. If no one is found, then look in a 5 x 5 square.

Comment: I mean to search for big white spaces to replace them and not for one or two that are randomly there?

Comment: Here's a beauty to test solutions with, an [RGB Venn Diagram](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/4b/27/81/4b27817bf9742f7555a16ad33996e2d0.jpg)

Comment: @Bob How will you find "big white spaces" in your image?

Comment: if there are more than a n number of consecutive pixels  then there is a white space, but is still an idea.

Comment: @Bob That's not reflected in your code sample at all. Please provide a code sample that exhibits a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Answer (score 1):

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

```
        Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        //pictureBox1_Paint.Image = bmp;
        // Draw myBitmap to the screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height);
        Color pix;
        Color pixx;

        for (int X = 1; X < myBitmap.Width-1; X++)
        {
            for (int Y = 1; Y < myBitmap.Height-1; Y++)
            {
                pix = myBitmap.GetPixel(X, Y);
                pixx = myBitmap.GetPixel(X, Y);
                Color pixwhite = myBitmap.GetPixel(X, Y);
                Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(X - 1, Y - 1);

                if (pix.R > 150 && pix.G > 150 && pix.B > 150)
                {
                    Color myWhite = new Color();
                    Color myColor = new Color();
                    myWhite = Color.FromArgb(pix.R, pix.G, pix.B);

                    if (pixx.R < 150 && pixx.G < 150 && pixx.B < 150)
                    {
                        myColor = Color.FromArgb(pixx.R, pixx.G, pixx.B);
                        if (pixwhite != pixelColor)
                        {
                            myBitmap.SetPixel(X, Y, myColor);

                        }

                    }

                    Color newcolor = new Color();

                    newcolor = Color.FromArgb(Math.Abs(pix.R - pixx.R) + Math.Abs(pix.G - pixx.G) + Math.Abs(pix.B - pixx.B));

                }
                //else
                //{  //myBitmap.SetPixel(X, Y, pix);
                 //   Color nearc = myBitmap.GetPixel(X, Y);
                //    myBitmap.SetPixel(X, Y, nearc);
                //}
            }
        }
        // Draw myBitmap to the screen again.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, myBitmap.Width, 0, myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height);
    }
```

[image]

The first one is the original, the second one is the "changed one"

Comment: What happens if `Pixel(0,0)` is white?

Comment: Did you find the answer to your own question?

Comment: Lets make a new image, completely white with the exception of the 4 corners which will be red, green, blue, and black in no particular order. What color should the rest of the image be? The color at (0,0)? or the color at (MaxX, MaxY) or something else. How about the following linear array `R-W-W-W-G`? I can see this easily becoming `R-R-x-G-G` but what does _x_ become? I would almost be tempted to make it **Y**. Now that I threw that at you, lets expand the thought process to realize that there will usually be another row above and below the offending **W**. Just call me the devil's advocate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace bad pixels with good ones, you not only need a way to identify bad ones, you also must have a way to identify good pixels. If you blindly take another pixel, that one might be bad as well.

I would take the average color of all good pixels around a bad one, i.e. look in a 3 x 3 square for good pixels, assuming that you only want to eliminate tiny bright spots.

```
// Search for good pixels and take their average color.
// The coordinates of the bad pixel are (X, Y).
int totR = 0, totG = 0, totB = 0, n = 0;
for (int i = X - 1; i <= X + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = Y - 1; j <= Y + 1; j++) {
        Color p = myBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
        if (p.R < 150 || p.G < 150 || p.B < 150) {
            // The pixel at [i, j] is a good one.
            totR += p.R; totG += p.G; totB += p.B;
            n++;
        }
    }
}
if (n > 0) {
    // We found at least one good pixel.
    myBitmap.SetPixel(X, Y, Color.FromArgb(totR / n, totG / n, totB / n));
}
```

If no one is found, you could then look in a 5 x 5 square (which is a bit more difficult, as you must stay inside the image).

Comment: I understand the idea, but i get a little error that says green value is 282 ... which is obviously not ok, is more than 255.

Comment: The first version had posted was wrong: `totG += p.B;`. Corrected it now to: `totB += p.B;`. (Both, green and blue were summed up in `totG`!)

Comment: Sorry, i was'n attentive. I tried for a square 5x5 and it's pretty the same thing for the image i used.